# In the South Park episode "Wing", what does Lu Kim scream at his wife?

Tags: dialogue, south-park

I don't know, If this question belongs here, but since I'm not sure what language it is about, I don't want to post it in a language specific site.

In the South Park episode 9.3 ("Wing") at 9:45 and 21:15 Tuong Lu Kim screams at his wife (presumably in Chinese).

I tried to use the transcriber of Google Translate, but without success.
What does he say to her? Is it really Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

Did actually ask a cantonese (hk) person (same origin as wing) about this and another segment and they said it was just rubbish, no actual words said.